# Add a space between two words

Tags: javascript

I have some words like "Light Purple" and "Dark Red" which are stored as "LightPurple" and "DarkRed". How do I check for the uppercase letters in the word like "LightPurple" and put a space in between the words "Light" and "Purple" to form the word "Light Purple".

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Would something like this work: `"LightPurple".replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/, '$1 $2')`?

Comment: You should add this as an answer @RocketHazmat ;)

Comment: [**This**](https://xkcd.com/208/) just happened.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a regex to add a space wherever there is a lowercase letter next to an uppercase one.

Something like this:

```
"LightPurple".replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/, '$1 $2')
```

**UPDATE**: If you have more than 2 words, then you'll need to use the `g` flag, to match them all.

```
"LightPurpleCar".replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
```

**UPDATE 2**: If are trying to split words like `CSVFile`, then you might need to use this regex instead:

```
"CSVFilesAreCool".replace(/([a-zA-Z])([A-Z])([a-z])/g, '$1 $2$3')
```

Comment: @Hazmat, still this regex does not fill my need, like what about this "CCVCode" wont split the string into "CCV Code" so I think the RE needs a little more tweak to address this issue. However, my custom Javascript deals with such examples. I have my answer just below yours. PS: I have voted your answer though :)

Comment: @KMX: Yeah, the regex isn't perfect, but for the OP's case, it may be good enough.

Comment: @KMX: I tried to update it.  That looks like it would work. :)

Comment: @Hazmat: Yea yea yea, you are almost there but still you missing one more thing (chuckle) what about "CSVFilesAreCoolButTXT" :)

Comment: @KMXL I'm not the best at regexes, but when I saw this question, that was the 1st solution I could think of :)

Comment: @Hazmat, (doh) nevermind... well i will find something pretty soon in regex but right now it seems my js does it right. :) Thanks for engaging dude.

Comment: @KMX Please could you ask a new question if _your requirements_ are different to the requirements on this question?

Comment: @andyb: KMX doesn't have a question, he's just messing with me :)

Comment: @andyb : (facepalm) well yea i do have a requirement but from regex prospective. I do have a javascript and/or an implementation of the same in another language (see my answer in this question). But the way hazmat put the regex was a so tidy so i worth adopting it instead of a 30-line code. Anyways, I will post a new question to address this since it worth knowing the answer.

Comment: @andyb here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369566/putting-space-in-camel-case-string-using-regular-expression

Comment: @RocketHazmat here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369566/putting-space-in-camel-case-string-using-regular-expression

Comment: Also, check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15369990/297114 ... the only case where this one fails is if the text ends with something like `xxxAAA`...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, sharing my experience. I have this implement in some other languages too it works superb. For you I just created a javascript version with an example so you try this:

```
var camelCase = "LightPurple";
var tmp = camelCase[0];
for (i = 1; i < camelCase.length; i++)
{
    var hasNextCap = false;
    var hasPrevCap = false;

    var charValue = camelCase.charCodeAt(i);
    if (charValue > 64 && charValue < 91)
    {
        if (camelCase.length > i + 1)
        {
            var next_charValue = camelCase.charCodeAt(i + 1);
            if (next_charValue > 64 && next_charValue < 91)
                hasNextCap = true;
        }

        if (i - 1 > -1)
        {
            var prev_charValue =  camelCase.charCodeAt(i - 1);
            if (prev_charValue > 64 && prev_charValue < 91)
                hasPrevCap = true;
        }


        if (i < camelCase.length-1 &&
            (!(hasNextCap && hasPrevCap || hasPrevCap)
            || (hasPrevCap && !hasNextCap)))
            tmp += " ";
    }
    tmp += camelCase[i];
}
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ayLjY/5/).

Answer (score 0):

You could compare each character to a string of uppercase letters.

```
function splitAtUpperCase(input){  
   var uppers = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";  
   //start at 1 because 0 is always uppercase
   for (var i=1; i<input.length; i++){
      if (uppers.indexOf(input.charAt(i)) != -1){
         //the uppercase letter is at i
         return [input.substring(0,i),input.substring(i,input.length)];
      }
   }
}
```

The output is an array with the first and second words.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is definitely not the best way to solve this problem (from an optimization perspective). But it works :)

```javscript
const createSpacesBetweenWords = (char, index) => {
  if (char === char.toUpperCase() && index > 0) {
    return ` ${char}`;
  }

  return char;
};

function formatString(string) {
  return string
    .split('')
    .map(createSpacesBetweenWords)
    .join('');
}

formatString('LightPurple'); //returns a new string where words are separated by spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex pattern that I came up with that should handle acronyms anywhere in the string:

```
"IOweTheIRSMoneyNOOOO".replace(/(?<!^)(([A-Z])([a-z]))|(([a-z])([A-Z]))/g, '$5 $2$3$6')
```