# Putting space in camel case string using regular expression

Tags: regex

I am driving my question from [add a space between two words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343163/add-a-space-between-two-words).

Requirement: Split a camel case string and put spaces just before the capital letter which is followed by a small case letter or may be nothing. The space should not incur between capital letters.

eg: `CSVFilesAreCoolButTXT` is a string I want to yield it this way `CSV Files Are Cool But TXT`

I drove a regular express this way:

```
"LightPurple".replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/, '$1 $2')
```

If you have more than 2 words, then you'll need to use the g flag, to match them all.

```
"LightPurpleCar".replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
```

If are trying to split words like `CSVFile` then you might need to use this regexp instead:

```
"CSVFilesAreCool".replace(/([a-zA-Z])([A-Z])([a-z])/g, '$1 $2$3')
```

But still it does not serve the way I have put my requirements.

Comment: Your last regex is only failing when it ends with uppercase letters. Eg. `...ButTXT`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
var rex = /([A-Z])([A-Z])([a-z])|([a-z])([A-Z])/g;

"CSVFilesAreCoolButTXT".replace( rex, '$1$4 $2$3$5' );
// "CSV Files Are Cool But TXT"
```

And also

```
"CSVFilesAreCoolButTXTRules".replace( rex, '$1$4 $2$3$5' );    
// "CSV Files Are Cool But TXT Rules"
```

The text of the subject string that matches the regex pattern will be replaced by the replacement string `'$1$4 $2$3$5'`, where the `$1`, `$2` etc. refer to the substrings matched by the pattern's capture groups `()`.

`$1` refers to the substring matched by the first `([A-Z])` sub-pattern, and `$3` refers to the substring matched by the first `([a-z])` sub-pattern etc.

Because of the alternation character `|`, to make a match the regex will have to match either the `([A-Z])([A-Z])([a-z])` sub-pattern or the `([a-z])([A-Z])` sub-pattern, so if a match is made several of the capture groups will remain unmatched. These capture groups can be referenced in the replacement string but they have have no effect upon it - effectively, they will reference an empty string.

The space in the replacement string ensures a space is inserted in the subject string every time a match is made (the trailing `g` flag means the regular expression engine will look for more than one match).

Comment: I would love to see the explanation of regex that you have defined, so the readers and newbie would know what exactly is happening with all those 1-2-3-4-5s.

Comment: Okay works best for what i have stated in my initial requirement. Now I am putting forward some more strees. So lets bang on it under this thread. Read the updates.

Comment: @KMX. I recommend you ask a new question to allow someone else the opportunity to get some credit for an accepted answer.

Comment: (doh) okay! it will be created shortly.

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374217/putting-space-in-camel-case-string-using-regular-expression-part-2

Answer (score 6):

If the first character is always lowercase.

```
'camelCaseString'.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, ' $1')
```

If the first character is uppercase.

```
'CamelCaseString'.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, ' $1').replace(/^ /, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

**Splitting CamelCase with regex in .NET :**

```
Regex.Replace(input, "((?<!^)([A-Z][a-z]|(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]))", " $1").Trim();
```

**Example :**

```
Regex.Replace("TheCapitalOfTheUAEIsAbuDhabi", "((?<!^)([A-Z][a-z]|(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]))", " $1").Trim();
```

**Output :**
The Capital Of The UAE Is Abu Dhabi

Comment: The `Trim()` doesn't seem to be required, well at least when migrating the solution to JavaScript at least.

Answer (score 2):

**This worked for me**

```
let camelCase = "CSVFilesAreCoolButTXTRules"
let re = /[A-Z-_\&](?=[a-z0-9]+)|[A-Z-_\&]+(?![a-z0-9])/g
let delimited = camelCase.replace(re,' $&').trim()
```

The above code works for almost all the use cases i had. I had a few peculiarities where '&' and '_' should be treated equivalent to an upper case character

- ThisIsASlug ---> This Is A Slug
- loremIpsum ---> lorem Ipsum
- PAGS_US ---> PAGS_US
- TheCapitalOfTheUAEIsAbuDhabi ---> The Capital Of The UAE Is Abu Dhabi
- eclipseRCPExt ---> eclipse RCP Ext
- VALUE ---> VALUE
- SG&A ---> SG&A

**A brief explanation**

```
[A-Z-_\&](?=[a-z0-9]+)
//Matches normal words i.e. one uppercase followed by one or more non-uppercase characters 


[A-Z-_\&]+(?![a-z0-9]) 
//Matches acronyms & abbreviations i.e. a sequence of uppercase characters that are not followed by non-uppercase characters
```

**[Check out the regexr fiddle here](https://regexr.com/69f1a)**

Answer (score 0):

Camel-case replacement for Javascript using **lookaheads / behinds**:

```
"TheCapitalOfTheUAEIsAbuDhabi".replace(/([A-Z](?=[a-z]+)|[A-Z]+(?![a-z]))/g, ' $1').trim()
// "The Capital Of The UAE Is Abu Dhabi"
```

Comment: "TheCapitáÖfTheUAEIsAbuDhabi".replace(/([A-Z](?=[a-z]+)|[A-Z]+(?![a-z]))/g, ' $1').trim()

fails, at least in Firefox's JS engine

Comment: One would have to account for unicode characters. The above only works for the ascii subset.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want also lower capital letters of all words except first.

```
function PascalCaseToText(str) {
  return str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, function(_, g1, g2) { return g1 + ' ' + g2.toLowerCase();  })
}

PascalCaseToText("SomePascalString");
// Some pascal string
```