# How to use regular expressions to insert space into a camel case string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regular expression to insert spaces into a camel-case string

```
var regex = /([A-Z])([A-Z])([a-z])|([a-z])([A-Z])/g;
```

Example usage

```
var str = "CSVFilesAreCoolButTXTRules";
str = str.replace( regex, '$1$4 $2$3$5' );
// "CSV Files Are Cool But TXT Rules"
```

This works fine, but I also want to put spaces before and after any numbers in the string, though I don't want space inserted between individual digits, and if a number is preceded by a `$` then the space should go before it, and not the number.

I also want to remove any characters apart from numbers, letters, the `$` sign and a dot `.` within a number.

For example,

> MRRPLowPriceUSD$10.10HighPriceUSD$1998.59595CommentsNoChangeReportedNTPL1001KSE-100INDEX

should become

> MRRP Low Price USD $10.10 High Price USD $1998.59595 Comments No Change Reported NTPL 1001 KSE 100 INDEX

Note that the `-` was removed.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Related: [putting-space-in-camel-case-string-using-regular-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369566/putting-space-in-camel-case-string-using-regular-expression).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this regex and replace using positive look-ahead:

```
var regex = /([^A-Za-z0-9\.\$])|([A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|([^\-\$\.0-9])(?=\$?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|([0-9])(?=[^\.0-9])|([a-z])(?=[A-Z])/g;
var str = "CSVFilesAreCool123B--utTXTFoo12T&XTRules$123.99BAz";
str = str.replace(regex, '$2$3$4$5 ');
// CSV Files Are Cool 123 B ut TXT Foo 12 T XT Rules $123.99 B Az
```

([RegExr](http://regexr.com?3444a))

Comment: hmm.. so close, but still a hyphen "-" not stripped off. How to address it? here is the running code http://jsfiddle.net/kreativemart/zEpjR/

Comment: @KMX Should _any_ hyphens be removed? And where do they occur? Only at the end/beginning of some substrings?

Comment: Examine the example to apply the RE here "1001KSE-100INDEX" so the hypen has to be removed.

Comment: @KMX I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: (clap) yea... i have marked it answered and upvoted. great job. I have another need though. Well this regex i use to split the camelcase and that i have in my datatable columns so generating dynamic forms and use the column name as the label. This regex will help me a lot. Now the other need comes when I am generating the SEF URLs, so anything other than letter/numbers should be replaced with one hypen as well as all repeating hyphens should become one. How to achieve that?

Comment: @KMX If you have another (even related) problem/task please create a separate question for that.