# How can I remove extra whitespace from my file names using power shell?

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, directory, filenames

I was trying to remove everything after a ( in a file name when I accidentally added a lot of whitespace to my file names when I ran this command

> Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "()"," "}

in power shell. I suppose it has something to do with not being explicit that the "()" characters were not part of some expression and I didn't realize it. I have a whole bunch of files with example names of

> H o w  T o  C r a f t () [.zip

or

> V i d e o  G a m e () [.zip

That have a space between each letter and two spaces between each word
That I now need to convert into

> How To Craft.zip
>
> Video Game.zip

and I am quite a novice on using regex and power shell in general. If someone could help me use a command to remove the double spacing between words, single spacing between letters and any instance of character ( and all text following a ( it would solve all my problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\s` regex whitespace character class to replace the spaces, `Trim()` to remove the special characters at the end and introduce spaces after each word with [this brilliant regex pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15370765/712649):

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem .\ -Name

$CamelCasePattern = '([A-Z])([A-Z])([a-z])|([a-z])([A-Z])'
$CamelCaseReplace = '$1$4 $2$3$5'

foreach($FileName in $Files){
    # Get the files base name
    $basename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($FileName)

    # Remember the extension
    $extension = $FileName.Substring($basename.Length)

    # Remove all whitespace
    $basename = $basename -ireplace '\s',''
    # Remove excess characters at the end
    $basename = $basename.TrimEnd('()[')
    # introduce space after each capitalized word
    $basename = $basename -creplace $CamelCasePattern,$CamelCaseReplace

    # return correct file name
    "$basename$extension"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the filenames with the following regex replacement:

```
 (?! )|[()\[\]]+ [()\[\]]+(?=\.)|( )
```

Or

```
\s(?!\s)|[()\[\]]+\s+[()\[\]]+(?=\.)|(\s)
```

And replacement is: `$1`.

See [demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/jW8bN8/5) or [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/jW8bN8/6).

So, it will now look like

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "\s(?!\s)|[()\[\]]+\s+[()\[\]]+(?=\.)|(\s)","$1"}
```

Comment: That removed all spaces from my files and did not remove the ()[**** that follows. The next step would be to add a space before any capitol letter.

Comment: Well, you can actually insert a space before each capital letter (with `(?<=\p{Lu})` => and `space` as replacement).